# Booting AWS EBS root Volume (Encrypted) to safe mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

All.

I would like to ask how to boot the root volume of the instance into safe mode? We have encrypted the Root volume previously and we need to boot it to safe mode to have the (SOPHOS) reinstalled. I have attached the encrypted volume on a free tier t2.micro instance and it does not allow me to edit it on the registry. Reference (https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/127602). Please help. Thanks

Comment: What fo you mean, *"it does not allow"* ...?  There seems to be no reason these steps would not work.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting "Access Denied" when I'm loading the hive of SYSTEM DB of the attached root drive. I've changed the permission of the DB file and performed PSexec but still having "Access Denied" prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone.

I have solved this (with the help of AWS Support). What I initially did was attached the root volume on a lower version of Windows Server (2008), which gave me the access denied error. I just need to use a free tier 2016 version of Windows to do the trick. Thanks!